# How to get the Source PeerID on IPFS

Tags: ipfs

Is there a way to get the source peer id in IPFS? I want to create a gateway and routing layer for a private swarm that will then record each peer "participation" activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IPFS [GO](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs) implementation or [Javascript](http://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs) implementation for creating gateway and routing layer for a private swarm

Comment: Yes but I wanted to figure out how to get the source peer id from a consuming peer.